# How can I return different values in a FormComponent method?

Tags: java, function, return-value, wicket, return-type

I have this method that is going to create 2 textfields and a combobox.
But I have a problem returning the different values because it gives me an error that "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ComboCustom to FormComponent<?>"

The 2 textfields work great, but I don´t understand why the combobox doesn´t and how to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

```
    private static FormComponent<?>[] criaComponentes(FiltroListaEquipamentosASerSubstituido2 filtro) {
        
        
        ComboCustom<EqpMarca> marca = new ComboCustom<EqpMarca>("marca", new PropertyModel<EqpMarca>(filtro, "marca"), list, new ChoiceRenderer<EqpMarca>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String getDisplayValue(EqpMarca est) {
                return est.getDesignacao();
            }

            @Override
            public String getIdValue(EqpMarca est, int arg) {
                return String.valueOf(est.getIdMarca());
            }
        });
        
        
        marca.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior(HtmlTag.ONCHANGE) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.add(marca);
            }
        });
        
        return new FormComponent<?>[] {
            new TextField<String>("nome", new PropertyModel<String>(filtro, "nome")),
            marca,
            new TextField<String>("modelo", new PropertyModel<String>(filtro, "modelo"))
        };
        
    }
```

Comment: Please put `FormComponent` and `ComboCustom` classes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`ComboCustom` seems to be an implementation of [IChoiceRenderer](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/b0c7d49bba73024ea0d1f6917e2f1437934cb6ae/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/IChoiceRenderer.java#L42). It is not really a [FormComponent](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/b0c7d49bba73024ea0d1f6917e2f1437934cb6ae/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.java)

Comment: So, how can I return a textfield + combocustom?

Comment: Since Java does not support tuples out of the box, e.g. `(formComponent, choiceRenderer)` you could return an `Object[]` or a custom Tuple/Pair class that holds the form component and the choice renderer.